# fetch and save http response before redirect using mechanize

Tags: python, redirect, mechanize

I am trying to fetch a sample page in python

```
import mechanize
 def viewpage(url):
  browser = mechanize.Browser()
  page = browser.open(url)
  source_code = page.read()
  print source_code
viewpage('https://sama.com/index.php?req=1')
```

However everytime it will get redirected  to index2.php (by a location header from webserver) thus for example the code print the response from index2.php rather than index.php is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: You just want to grab the source code of a web-page?

Comment: Yes just to grab the source. so I can parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for more complex stuff.

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
page_source = response.read()
```

`urllib2` is a built-in module and `requests` is 3rd party.

Comment: thats not correct since the urllib2.urlopen will follow the redirect. While I don't want such thing happen.

Comment: @SamaAzari, Well the url in your example doesn't redirect and I don't want to go out looking for a webpage.  I just don't know of any off the top of my head.